# Was bedeutet dieser Satz aus «Deutsch für junge Profis»

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, book

Hier sind ein paar Sätze aus «Deutsch für junge Profis». Ich verstehe den letzten Satz nicht, bitte erklären Sie ihn.

- Habe ich meinen Ehrgeiz richtig eingesetzt, um beim Wettlauf um die Aufmerksamkeit mit vorn dabei zu liegen?
- Habe ich mein Vorhaben auf mögliche Pointen abgeklopft?

(Übrigens geht es darum, wie man einen guten Artikel schreibt.)

Comment: _,,Habe ich mein Vorhaben auf mögliche Pointen angeklopft?''_ Ist Unsinn. Gewiss ein Druckfehler. Es soll wohl ,,Habe ich mein Vorhaben auf mögliche Pointen a**b**geklopft?'' heissen.

Comment: Hättest du nicht "letzte Wort" schreiben wollen?

Comment: Was genau verstehst Du nicht? Ist ein bestimmtes Wort unklar?

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich habe falsch getippt. Es ist wirklich ,,abklopfen''.   ich verstehe nicht was bedeutet abklopfen in diesem Satz. Und was ist das ,,Pointen" ? Dank für die Antwort:)

Answer (score 5):

Ein Artikel ist atttraktiver, wenn der Leser nicht nur Informationen entgegennimmt, sondern gleichzeitig auch unterhalten wird. Darum rät der letzte Satz, sich zu überlegen, wie man den Artikelinhalt mit Pointen aufwerten könnte.

Eine Pointe ist ein humoristischer Knalleffekt. »Auf Pointen abklopfen« heißt in diesem Fall so viel wie »den Artikelinhalt nach Stellen durchsuchen, an denen man Pointen unterbringen kann«.

Wenn du einen Artikel über Autos schreibst, könntest du z. B. Folgendes erwähnen:

> - Das erste Auto war das Pferd.
> - Der Wagen hat insgesamt 92 PS, davon 2 der Scheibenwischer.
> - Einen Kleinwagen fährt man ja immer dann, wenn sich die Türen nach außen öffnen.

Comment: Schöne Beispiele! Ich glaube aber, das erste Auto war das Rind.

Comment: Danke! Das ist so hilfreiche.:)

Comment: *hilfreich* (ohne e)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Wenn du Rind sagst, sag ich Mammut.

Answer (score 4):

Die bildliche Redewenung

> etwas auf etwas abklopfen

spielt auf folgende Situation an: Du suchst etwas, zum Beispiel deinen davongelaufenes Kaninchen, und gehst im Garten umher. Das Kaninchen ist nirgends zu sehen, aber da ist die Hecke, in die du nicht hineinsehen kannst. Also fängst du an, mit der Hand oder einem Stock auf die Büsche zu schlagen (klopfen), und so klopfst du die ganze Hecke ab. Wenn das Kaninchen drin ist, wird es irgendwann heraushoppeln.

Oder nimm dieses Bild: Du bist in einem fremden Haus und suchst ein Versteck in der Wand, wo du einen Schatz vermutest (oder Trumps Steuererklärung). Du klopfst die Wände systematisch ab, um herauszufinden, wo vielleicht hohle Stellen sind.

"Klopfen" ist in der Regel eine auf einen Ort begrenzte Tätigkeit. "Etwas abklopfen" impliziert, dass das Klopfen systematisch über eine größere räumliche Fläche vorgenommen wird.

Das praktische Abklopfen aus den Beispielen mit der Hecke und dem Haus kannst du metaphorisch auf auch andere Such-Aktivitäten anwenden. Die Formulierung ist allerdings etwas flappsig, also nicht gut zu gebrauchen im allgemeinen (geschäftlichen) Schriftverkehr.

Beispiele für einen mehr oder weniger realistischen Einsatz der Wendung:

> Ich klopfe meinen Bekannenkreis mal auf Kenntnisse beim Fenstereinbau ab, vielleicht findet sich einer, der mir da helfen kann.
>
> Die Parteivorsitzende klopft die Ortsvereine nach ihrer Meinung zur Bürgerversicherung ab.
>
> Jemand hat mit einem Fußball eine Scheibe zertrümmert. Ich klopfe mal die Schüler im Schulhof ab, ob einer was dazu weiß.

Comment: Ich stelle mir beim Abklopfen immer einen Teppich vor, aus dem ein kleiner Gegenstand, zum Beispiel eine Nadel, heraus fällt.

Comment: Danke!  Es ist sehr hilfreich. Jetzt kann ich verstehen.:)